# Too big addon list, what should I do? How expand names and keep it all?

Tags: interface, add-on, workspaces

There are many addons. Do you know how show it in two cloumns?[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First make sure you really need all addons you have active, having many active simultaneously may eventually have a significant toll on responsiveness and available resources. Disable any you don't really need.

Features are often grouped for certain steps or stages of a project. You may notice you only need certain addons during particular tasks or phases, maybe even use a few of them simultaneously in groups, but not all at the same time.

If that is the case you can set up workspaces dedicated to specific tasks where you will pick a few addons you generally use in tandem relevant for that step of a larger workflow (say modelling phase, texturing, shading, animation etc.).

Once created you can take advantage per workspace addon filters. In the *3D View Toolshelf*, (expand it with the <kbd>N</kbd> key) go to the *Tools* tab, *Workspace* panel, activate *Filter Addons*.

There you can pick which addons are active for that specific workspace. Choose only the relevant ones for those particular tasks you do in that workspace.

[image]

Also see related [Addon to customize tabs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119787/19307)

Comment: Thank you, it's good advice about creating workspaces