# User Profiles with specific Add-ons loaded?

Tags: customization

Is there an option to create custom user profile that has all of the preference options saved to that profile?

Would be wonderful to have my tools available to me, at least visually, always.
But this is turning out to be impossible in the way that blender displays add-ons on the side.

Then it would at least be nice to have seperate profiles with seperate tools loaded via splash screen or in some other form.

Do I have to install 4 versions of Blender?

Has anyone else ever thought of this or made a tool for just that?

Comment: This also sounds like overkill. Blender has workspaces which can have per workspace enabled or disabled addons, for each separate workflow https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172502/too-big-addon-list-what-should-i-do-how-expand-names-and-keep-it-all

Comment: Awesome!!!!! Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted