# blender 3.2 - N pannel Addons tabs to small

Tags: 3d-view

Sometimes there are so many addons the names are not visible.
Is there a way to on mouse over "tool tip" the N Pannel addons to see the name, or make the tabs larger?
[image: npannel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution #1 - Filter add-ons

[image]

---

## Solution #2 - Zoom in/out tab sizes

You can use <kbd>CTRL + MMB-drag</kbd> to adjust the size of your right, 3D viewport sidebar. This method can be similarly done to other UI panels to adjust their sizes as well.

### Video - Footage

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XM0E5HEyMIA

### Screenshot - Before

[image]

### Screenshot - After

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting that result. Are you clicking in the viewport, or on the actual tabs?
 "CTRL + LMB-drag to adjust the size of your right, 3D viewport sidebar"

Comment: ctrl+ MIDDLE MOUSE did work, except it does the opposite. the smaller the tabs the more text. the larger the tab, the tab text disappears because it's getting to big to fit in the tab area.

Comment: [1] Click-dragging either the viewport panel or the panel tabs works. [2] I made a typo in my post when saying, "LMB," instead of, "MMB," as you caught. [3] See this answer on how to filter those 3rd-party tabs: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172505/123064