Automatically iInstall an extension when a Blender application template is installed?
I am in the process of porting my addon (BlenderFDS, http://blenderfds.org) to Blender 4.2.
I have been maintaining this addon for ten years now. BlenderFDS is an open source preprocessor for physical fire simulation in buildings with NIST Fire Dynamics Simulator, an open source computational fluid dynamics solver.
I am transforming it into an app template.
How to automatically install an extension when the application template is opened? Could you point me to an example?
Can I embed the extension into the application template?
I cannot find any reference on that.
Thank you in advance.

Can't help directly with your question as I've never used them, but I assume you've read right through the section in the Blender 4.2 manual ? There's also a 1 hour long 'Extensions LIVE Q&A' here which might be of use.

Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

Yes, I read the blender 4.2 manual several times. I did not find any clue.

Harry, my original question was closed, and this question does not seem to me the same as before. But let me know if I did something wrong and I'll try to fix it.

I also watched the live q&a

From my limited knowledge in the area, you can't really install or uninstall addons from an application template, but you can enable or disable them accordingly. They have to technically be installed beforehand, or be installed  along with the application template itself. The template can then enable them or provide a custom folder for addons containing the addon. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html Alternatively disable it by workspace https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172502/too-big-addon-list-what-should-i-do-how-expand-names-and-keep-it-all/
